# Both preDebugBuild and preReleaseBuild getting called by Gradle

Tags: android, gradle

I am trying to assemble a debug build type of a library for Android.

I have set this code in my gradle script:

```
task setDebug(dependsOn: 'preDebugBuild') {
    project.ext.set("pathType", "debug")
    println('DEBUG')
}

task setRelease(dependsOn: 'preReleaseBuild') {
    project.ext.set("pathType", "release")
    println('RELEASE')
}
```

Thing is, when I run gradle with:

```
gradle assembleDebug
```

Both DEBUG and RELEASE get printed on the screen and thus my pathType variable is always 'release'. However in the gradle output I can only see the Debug tasks being called.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

The blocks are executed during the configuration phase. If you would like to defer the code block from being evaluated till execution phase then you could use a pattern like this

```
task setDebug(dependsOn: 'preDebugBuild') << {
    // ...
}
```

This will wait till the actual execution of the task instead of the configuration of the task to evaluate the closure.

The way your currently doing it would result in both blocks of code being evaluated every time gradle is executed.  For example right now if you just ran `gradle` without specifying a task you would see both `println` statements in the logs.  Using `<<` should fix your issue of the closure being evaluated no matter the tasks.

Comment: Actually when I use this none of them get executed :(